# Apache camel file name with current date

Tags: apache-camel

Is it possible to provide dynamic file name which includes date in camel file destination end point?

I am having below in my application.yaml

```
destination-end-point-file: file:/H:/temp?fileName=${date:now:yyyyMMdd}
```

which is throwing below exception.

```
 java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 11: H:\temp\now:yyyyMMdd
```

I would like have output something like below

some_file_name_20190717.csv

How do I make camel evaluate expression `${date:now:yyyyMMdd}`

Answer (score 1):

You can update something in the properties file such as:

```
tp.position.destination-end-point-file=file:/output/location? 
fileName=ps_open_txn_batch_$simple{date:now:yyyyMMdd}.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve it by adding expression in java route, not sure why it does not evaluate the expression when it reads from spring properties file.

in Java Route

```
.to("{{tp.position.destination-end-point-file}}" + "?fileName=ps_open_txn_batch_${date:now:yyyyMMdd}.csv")
```

in application.yaml

```
destination-end-point-file: file:/H:/temp
```